# Prove that $\lim_{z \to i} |1-z|^2=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $\lim_{z \to i} |1-z|^2=2$.

I let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta$ = (blank, since I don't know what to choose yet)

When $|z - i| < \delta$, $||1 - z|^2 - 2| ≤ |(1 - z)^2 - 2| = |z^2 - 2z - 1|.$

And then I'm stuck. I'm not sure how I can extract out a $|z - i| < \delta$ in order to further the proof.

Comment: It isn't true that $\;|1-z|^2=(1-z)^2\;$ in $\;\Bbb C\;$ . For example, the left side is always real, whereas the right one is always complex non-real if $\;\text{Im}(z)\neq0\;$

Comment: I do know that $|1 - z|^2$ is not always equal to $(1-z)^2$, but I was thinking of using the reverse triangle inequality, which states that |a - b| ≥ ||a| - |b||. So I took a = $|1 - z|^2 = |(1-z)^2|$ and b = 2 = |2|. Was that a wrong assumption to make?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the identification $\;\Bbb C\sim\Bbb R^2\;$ and then

$$\lim_{z\to i}|1-z|^2=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}||(1,0)-(x,y)||^2=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)}\left[(1-x)^2+y^2\right]=1^2+1^2=2$$

Comment: And this is still not a $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Comment: and isn't this proof based on the assumption that we approach x and y from the left and right side? Whereas with a $\epsilon-\delta$ proof (and the fact that it is on the complex plane), we would have to approach from every direction.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, it is not. I didn't read that was a condition, although the poster tried it.

Comment: @Cici What left and right sides? We're on the plane: there are infinite number of direction, and in the proof there is nothing that restricts them.

Comment: @Joanpemo To be honest it's not necessary. Your proof is as useful as saying $\lim \limits_{z\to i}\left(|1-z|^2\right)=2$. You use polynomials in $\mathbb R^2$, I use them in $\mathbb C$. But a proof that at least one of them works is required.

Comment: @Joanpemo, when I said "left and right side", I meant the idea that is used in single variable calculus on the reals, where one would observe the limit of $x \to 1^+$ and $x \to 1^-$. And to me your proof doesn't look like it is using the idea that we're approaching i from all directions. 

Perhaps I'm just misunderstanding something, but would it be possible to do a $\epsilon-\delta$ proof? (out of curiosity)

Comment: @GitGud I used the idea that a polynomial in any number of variables is always contunuous anywhere and thus its limit is just substituting, and I guess it is possible to do it the same over the rationals or over the complex.

Comment: @Cici If you see any restriction on any direction in my proof please do tell me. I just can't see any. About an $\;\epsilon-\delta\;$ proof: I'll post something if I come up with some idea.

Comment: @Joanpemo I suppose it's because I don't see any restrictions, hence why I'm hesitant. And your proof just seemed to be too simple and too elegant. (I'm not very good with $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs, hence why I'm often unsure of what I can and can't claim in them).

Answer (score 2):

You will have hard time bounding the distance this way. $\varepsilon-\delta$ tricks work well if you use more "homogenous" inequalities **or** you should decompose it to an atomic level (But thats just my two cents)...
Write $z=x+iy$, then:
$$||1-z|^2-2| =|(1-x)^2 +y^2 -2|=|-2x+x^2+y^2-1| \tag1 $$
Recall we have $\delta^2 > |z-i|^2 =x^2+(y-1)^2 $, so obviously enough: $|x|<\delta$ and $|y-1| < \delta$

Returning to $(1)$ we have: $$|-2x+x^2+y^2-1|\leq|x||-2+x| + |y-1||y+1| $$

Which can be bounded in terms of delta (I leave it to you).

Comment: Oh thank you! A quick question though, when you said:
$||1 - z|^2 - 2| = |(1 + x)^2 + y^2 - 2|$
Shouldn't it be $|(1 - x)^2 + y^2 - 2|$?

Comment: @Cici, you are right!

Comment: @Ranc Alrighty! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Cici Yes, you are right. But it's worth mentioning that the reason i could still bound it is because we can define $z=-x+iy$... (Thats why there wasn't any "crucial" mistake in the next steps...)